# Firestore: Flutter pugin, error when trying to sort the data by a field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to sort a document stored in Firestore by a field of integers, but while trying to do so, I got this error.  `type Query is not a subtype of type Collection Reference`

My code is

```
final CollectionReference timetableCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('timetables').orderBy('Period');
```

where period only contain integers.The code works fine if I don't do the orderBy part.
I looked at the documentation and it says CollectionReference extends on Query so I don't understand where to fix.

Comment: This doesn't look like complete code.  Please edit the question to show the code that anyone can use to reproduce the issue, and be sure to explain fully what the error message is referring to.

Comment: Sorry, my formatting messed up and only showed the last part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you can see from the API documentation that `collection()` returns a CollectionReference, and `orderBy()` returns a Query.

It's true that CollectionReference is a subclass of Query.  However, that doesn't mean that all Query objects are also CollectionReference objects.  It means that **all CollectionReference objects are also Query objects**.

If you want to use a common data type, use Query.  These lines of code should both compile:

```
final Query timetableQuery = Firestore.instance.collection('timetables'); 
final Query timetableOrderedQuery = Firestore.instance.collection('timetables').orderBy('Period');
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the error. However, it turns out that **CollectionReference** datatype is needed because I used `timetableCollection.document().setData(...)` in another function. So, I ended up declaring both datatypes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.